# Issue with mapping timestamp field in json to java.sql.Timestamp

Tags: java, json, spring-boot, timestamp

I am trying to pass a json input to a spring rest endpoint. JSON has one of the field as:

```
"timestamp": "2017-04-12 10:12:31.4610"
```

In domain class, corresponding field is:

```
@JsonFormat(pattern="yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.SSSX")
Timestamp timestamp;
```

But I get deserialization issue with this field:

```
HttpMessageNotReadableException: JSON parse error: Cannot deserialize value of type `java.sql.Timestamp` from String "2017-04-12 10:12:31.4610": not a valid representation (error: Failed to parse Date value '2017-04-12 10:12:31.4610': Cannot parse date "2017-04-12 10:12:31.4610": while it seems to fit format 'yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSSX', parsing fails (leniency? null))
```

I also tried with:

```
@JsonFormat(pattern="yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSSX")
Timestamp timestamp;
```

But same error is thrown.

What mistake am I making here?

Comment: can you try @JsonFormat(shape=JsonFormat.Shape.STRING,pattern="yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSS'Z'")
Timestamp timestamp;

Comment: I tried, but same issue.

Comment: The error message is not completely correct. `2017-04-12 10:12:31.4610` does *not* fit format `yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSSX` (do you see why?)

Comment: I recommend you don’t use `Timestamp`. That class is poorly designed and long outdated. Instead use one of `OffsetDateTime`, `Instant` and `LocalDateTime`, all from [java.time, the modern Java date and time API](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/).